# How to write Cramer-Von Mises p-values loop?

Tags: r, sapply, p-value

I have this matrix called `matrix_1`:

```
    c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
R1  27  38  94  40  4
R2  69  16  85  2   15
R3  30  35  64  95  6
R4  20  33  77  98  55
R5  20  44  60  33  89
R6  12  88  87  44  38
```

I would like to run a two-sample Cramer-Von Mises test (cvm_test()) in a loop to compare the distribution of each column with a vector `vector_a`. I want the function to just return the p-value.

I am trying this:

`library(twosamples)`

```
sapply(1:ncol(matrix_1), function(i) cvm_test(as.vector(matrix_1[,1:i]), vector_a)$cvm_test[2,])
```

but I am getting an error result:

```
Error in cvm_test(matrix_1,  : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: Read the manual page. The second argument of `cmv.test` is "A function, or a character string giving the name of a function, to compute the cumulative distribution function for the null distribution." A vector is not a function or the name of a function.

Comment: clarification - using twosamples pkg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the p-value by using [[2]], e.g.

```
sapply(1:ncol(matrix_1), function(i) cvm_test(as.vector(matrix_1[,1:i]), vector_a)[[2]]) #just values as vector
```

or using [2], e.g.

```
sapply(1:ncol(matrix_1), function(i) cvm_test(as.vector(matrix_1[,1:i]), vector_a)[2]) #named values as vector
```

In the manual, you can read that "Output is a length 2 Vector with test stat and p-value in that order".